# How does the buck regulator soft start condition reduce the unwanted voltage drops from high impedance power sources?

Tags: voltage, buck, switching-losses

I have been studying the functionality of the soft start function. I understood how it will help to reduce the overshoot of the output voltage as well. [Here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62162.pdf?ts=1600022473074&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS62162), my intention is to understand the meaning of following highlighted terms.

Any explanation with a practical scenario would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During startup, a buck converter without soft start will attempt to charge its output capacitors as quickly as possible.  The control loop will likely saturate causing the regulator to put out maximum duty cycle.

Since I = C*dv/dt, that means a large current to charge the caps.  If your supply to the buck converter has a relatively high impedance the large inrush current could cause the input supply to drop in voltage, potentially causing other parts on the same rail to reset or brown out.

By controlling the start up of the buck with a soft-start, the "dt" term is longer so the inrush current is lower.

Comment: What if the input voltage is also an output of another buck ? Can we we consider the buck that provides the input voltage as a high impedance source ?

Comment: @student7 Usually no, due to the feedback and high loop gain a buck converter is a very low impedance source.  There are some exceptions, but a normal buck converter isn't a high impedance source.